# Enable rotate/resize video with WPF in visual studio 2010

Tags: wpf

I'm developing this multitouch app in WPF with visual studio 2010.

I have the follow problem:

I'm trying to use the rotate,scaling and other effect with multitouch (like gallery in ipad style).

Can anyone tell me how to do that with a MEDIA ELEMENT?For the image as you see i haven't problem,and the rotate/scaling works fine.

The source is the follow:

```
<Window x:Class="TouchRect.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TouchRect" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
<Grid Width="auto">
    <local:RulerCanvas x:Name="canvas"  >
        <!--<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"    Height="215" Width="736">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>-->
        <Image x:Name="image3" Width="74" Height="49" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Source="flower3.jpg" Canvas.Left="239" Canvas.Top="-273">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="2.41806325085411,0,0,2.41806325085411,280.737615796121,292.420001677231" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image x:Name="image2" Width="64" Height="49" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Source="flower2.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Canvas.Left="-236" Canvas.Top="-272">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform  Matrix="2.41806325085411,0,0,2.41806325085411,280.737615796121,292.420001677231"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0"></StackPanel>


        <Image x:Name="image" Width="74" Height="49" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Source="flower.jpg" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="-7" Canvas.Top="-271">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="2.41806325085411,0,0,2.41806325085411,280.737615796121,292.420001677231" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv" Width="633" Height="366" Canvas.Left="65" Canvas.Top="164" LoadedBehavior="Manual" IsManipulationEnabled="True" />

        <!--</ListBox>-->  
    </local:RulerCanvas>

</Grid>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did not mean that you should ask the exact same question but to ask about getting an embedded reference/interactivity to work. This convers the exact same thing as your previous question **which is besides the point** and it violated the guidelines.

Comment: I'm sorry! I think you mean to ask the question so anyone else can read and help.

Comment: Once a question is asked the only "legitimate" ways to get attention to it are via bounties or relevant edits which bump the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate a media element, you should be able to do it like this:

```
<MediaElement Source="vid.wmv">
   <MediaElement.LayoutTransform>
       <TransformGroup>
           <RotateTransform Angle="-30"/>
       </TransformGroup>
   </MediaElement.LayoutTransform>
</MediaElement>
```

Comment: Oh thanks! But i have to do it in multitouch situation. Then in a pinch to zoom or rotate with two finger. Like ipad style.

Comment: If you know how to handle touch inputs in wpf, you'll be able to calculate the angle and than apply that angle to your media element. Here is a example of how to read touch inputs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090.aspx